# How to know whether any changes in the jtextarea have been made or not?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I've created a jtextarea where a user can modify its content. I want to know,if there is any way, whether the user has modified its content or not before closing the application. Please help.
  -Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to the [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) that backs the text area.

Then in the callback methods (insertUpdate(), removeUpdate(), changedUpdate()) of the listener, simply set a flag that something has changed and test that flag before closing the application

```
public class MyPanel
  implements DocumentListener
{
  private boolean changed;

  public MyPanel()
  {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    .....
  }

  .....

  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    changed = true;
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    changed = true;
  }
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    changed = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the value of jtextarea and compare this value to the value of jtextarea in the moment of application closing.

Pseudocode here, doesn't remember the excact syntax of text area:

```
String oldText = textarea.getText();
....

// not the exact method, just to point the moment of application exit 
public onClose() {

  String newText = textArea.getText();
  // assuming oldText is not null
  if (oldText.equals(newText)) {
     // no changes have been done
  } else {
   // the value changed
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any less tedious solution for this? For frequent use comparing the whole text will be a very heavy task because i've very large texts. Is there no predefined function to detect even a single character change?

Comment: I afraid this a simple one. You can write an intelligent detection system for the cases when user removes the character and put it back. In that case the event model will tell you, that text has been changed, but it is not true.