# Update a JTextArea dynamically depending on users JTextField values

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I have two JTextField which take numbers from users, like this:

```
nbMuscle = new JTextField();
nbMuscle.setText("2");
```

and this:

```
nbFuyard = new JTextField();
nbFuyard.setText("1");
```

my JTextArea() takes make an addition of both JTextField's values, like this:

```
nbPersonnages = new JTextArea();
int nombMusc = Integer.valueOf(nbMuscle.getText());
int nombFuy = Integer.valueOf(nbFuyard.getText());
int nbTotal = nombMusc + nombFuy;
nbPersonnages.setText(String.valueOf(nbTotal));
```

It works like a charm but I have one problem, if the user edit one of the JTextFields, the JTextArea value don't change. I have found on internet some notions like jTextArea.appened(String str) but it doesn't work.

Any idea of what I could do?

Comment: put settext code in a method and recall method when textarea update .see this for update event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836224/how-to-know-whether-any-changes-in-the-jtextarea-have-been-made-or-not

Comment: You need to monitor changes on your text fields and update the value stored in text area in this case. Look how to [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `DocumentListener` to the underlying `Document` of the TextFields to listen to changes made while the program runs.
The easiest way to do this is proboably an anonymous class.
Here is the Code:

```
nbMuscle = new JTextField();
nbMuscle.setText("2");
nbFuyard = new JTextField();
nbFuyard.setText("1");

nbPersonnages = new JTextArea();

DocumentListener dl = new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // This method is not called when the text of the Document changed, but if attributes of the Document changed.
    }

    private void textChanged() {
        int nombMusc = Integer.valueOf(nbMuscle.getText());
        int nombFuy = Integer.valueOf(nbFuyard.getText());
        int nbTotal = nombMusc + nombFuy;
        nbPersonnages.setText(String.valueOf(nbTotal));
    }
};

int nombMusc = Integer.valueOf(nbMuscle.getText());
int nombFuy = Integer.valueOf(nbFuyard.getText());
int nbTotal = nombMusc + nombFuy;
nbPersonnages.setText(String.valueOf(nbTotal));

nbMuscle.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dl);
nbFuyard.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dl);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I have adapted your answer to my code and I have two errors, nombMusc.getDocument() and nombFuy.getDocument() are returning a `Cannot invoke getDocument() on the primitive type int`, have I done something wrong?

Comment: I think you mixed up the variables `nombMusc` and `nbMuscle`. The `getDocument()` has to be invoked on the TextField called `nbMuscle` not on the int `nombMusc`. The same applies for `nombFuy` and `nbFuyard`.

Comment: Indeed, made mistakes on those variables. Thanks a lot.